# Center PopOver view when display from navigation bar using FPPopover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, popover, fppopover

I am using [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover) to display a popover view in my iPhone application, and the problem is that I can't center the popover, you will understand what I mean if you see the image below.

Both of my navigation bar buttons display a different popover views , but I want the center them , and as you can see it's aligned to the right.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM6pg.png]